# Laravel display multiple selected values

Tags: php, laravel

How can I display correctly from multiple selected value. I have tables for the suppliers that can connect to products, I used implode to combine the selected values. My problem is when retrieve only one value selected can't read the others selected

```
$selected = array($products->supplier_id);

<select  name="supplier_id[]" multiple="multiple">
   @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
         <?php  $isSelected = in_array($supplier->id,$selected) ? "selected='selected'" : ""; ?>
   <option {{ $isSelected }} value="{{ $supplier->id }}">{{ $supplier->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$selected = explode(",", $products->supplier_id);

<select  name="supplier_id[]" multiple="multiple">
   @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
     <option value="{{ $supplier->id }}" {{ (in_array($supplier->id, $selected)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $supplier->name}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Hello @enriqg9 same output

Comment: @BenjGonzales What is the value of `$selected`?

Comment: $selected = array(1,2,3); and soon on

Comment: maybe I have problem from my database

Comment: @BenjGonzales probably.. what I show you is pretty simple.. php will add the `selected` attribute if the needle matches the array.. replace the in_array portion to something you know is true and the value will be selected.. ie. `in_array(1, [1,2])`

Comment: Sir @enriqg9, It's working when manually put numbers on array but from my database is not working :( here's my value from my database "1,2,3" varchar

Comment: @BenjGonzales if you are saving your data in a single column you need to explode your data by your delimiter to properly convert it to an array.. in this case ','.. try $selected = explode(",", $products->supplier_id);

Comment: yehey! thank you very much Sir @enriqg9 :) its working

Comment: @BenjGonzales glad it helped ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = explode(',',$drawings->machine_id);

{!! Form::select('machine[]', $machines, $array, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple', 'required' => '']) !!}
```

This is what I did and it works...